# where has geth fast-sync mode gone?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, geth

I'v read several articles about geth full sync mode which can be enabled by `--syncmode full` option.
But why am I getting error `unknown sync mode fast want full snap or light` when use that option?
I want to get only block receipts without processing the state.
Which sync mode should I use?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

`--syncmode snap` option (which is the default) should work in your case.
See Snap sync at https://blog.ethereum.org/2021/03/03/geth-v1-10-0/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).